# Method returns false in method call, but actually returns true to the callee in Android app

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio

So I know I should post code, but my code is fairly complex and I don't think it'll help.

This method:

```
public boolean placePlayer(Player player, int startingX, int startingY)
{
    if(checkNotOnBoard(startingX, startingY))
        return false;
    player.setStartingPosition(startingX, startingY);
    placeStartingTile(startingX, startingY);
    return true;
}
```

calls checkNotOnBoard(), which is:

```
private boolean checkNotOnBoard(int positionX, int positionY)
{
    if(_board.length < 1)
        return true;
    if(positionX < 0 || positionY < 0)
        return true;
    if((positionX < _board.length) && (positionY < _board[0].length))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

I set the debugging breakpoint at if(checkNotOnBoard(startingX, startingY)), stepped through the method, it went to the last line in that method (return false), when it returned to placePlayer, however, the return was true, and placePlayer moved to the return false line.
The only theory I have is that _board is being reset, but as far as I can tell, there is no other thread that is running this section of the code.  It is an android app, and I am debugging on an HTC One M8 device and Nexus 7 using Android Studio.

Comment: Yes, sometimes debugging is buggy....

Comment: try like this : `value=checkNotOnBoard(startingX, startingY) ; if(value)
        return false;`

Comment: Tried, it.  value=true, even though checkNotOnBoard() returns false.

Comment: Better to assign return value in a variable and at the end, return that variable value in `checkNotOnBoard`..

Comment: `private boolean checkNotOnBoard(int positionX, int positionY)
{
    var val = false;
    if(_board.length < 1)
        val=true;
    else if(positionX < 0 || positionY < 0)
        val =true;
    else if((positionX < _board.length) && (positionY < _board[0].length))
        val=true;
    return val;
}`

Comment: What happens if you move the content of `checkNotOnBoard` inside `placePlayer` ?

Comment: @PhilippeA, the answer below was correct.  The debugger wasn't displaying the correct line that was being executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The debugger always hits the last line of a method when a return is executed.  It doesn't actually mean the last statement was executed.  What may be happening is the java engine pops the return address off the stack at the last line.

Comment: It's a good thought, but I checked the variables that are being checked in checkNotOnBoard() during the debug and none of those if conditions should result in true.  Additionally, as I step through, the debugger never hits one of the "return true" statements.

Comment: Report it to google as an issue if you think that the boolean is coming out of the function correctly.  I'd guess your having a learning curve issue with bitwise comparison.  && ||.  Because every android app would have issues if that wasn't the case.

Comment: Disregard my last comment, you're right:
Turns out that the last if:
if((positionX < _board.length) && (positionY < _board[0].length))
was returning true, but the debugger was skipping over that return true statement and jumped straight to the return false statement.  Kind of odd behavior, but you guessed it!